# How to test a sendgrid-nodejs function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I created a firebase function to send mail using sendgrid, but don't know how to test my function. Below is my code:

```
import * as sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail';
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

const SENDGRID_API_KEY = functions.config().sendgrid.key;
const SENDGRID_TEMPLATE_ID = functions.config().sendgrid.template_id;
const SENDGRID_FROM_EMAIL = functions.config().sendgrid.sender.email;
const SENDGRID_FROM_NAME = functions.config().sendgrid.sender.name;

sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);

interface MailData {
    subject: String;
    name: String;
    otherField: String;
}

interface Mailer {
    email: String;
    name?: String;
}

interface MailObject {
    to: Mailer;
    dynamic_template_data: MailData;
}

function sendEmail (mailObject: MailObject) {
    const msg = {
        to: mailObject.to,
        from: {
            email: SENDGRID_FROM_EMAIL,
            name: SENDGRID_FROM_NAME
        },
        templateId: SENDGRID_TEMPLATE_ID,
        substitutionWrappers: ['{{', '}}'],
        dynamic_template_data: mailObject.dynamic_template_data
    }
    console.log(msg);
    return sgMail.send(msg);
}

export default sendEmail;
```

How can I test the sendEmail function (write a unit test or the same, not send and open mailbox and check mail)?

Comment: Instead of using Sendgrid directly I use Nodemailer. Using Nodemailer you can use any mail provider. Nodemailer also has Nodemailer Mock to test it out. https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer